# Get Array Of Object On ajax Call success

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I will make Ajax call on my Controller action method. I want result of JSON in this format.

```
// array of all brands
    var brands = [
        { brandId: 1, name: "Ford" },
        { brandId: 2, name: "BMW" }
    ];
```

for this i will make another call

```
// array of all models
var models = [
    { modelId: 1, name: "Explorer", brandId: 1},
    { modelId: 2, name: "Focus", brandId: 1},
    { modelId: 3, name: "X3", brandId: 2},
    { modelId: 4, name: "X5", brandId: 2}
];
```

How can i do that please guide me.

Comment: Show your controller code and the ajax calls.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have to write code i have all this value in my db but it is not possible with select iteam list

Comment: What does `SelectListItem` have to do with it? You have said you want json.

Comment: Create the necessary classes based on the JSON format that you want. You can generate C# classes based on the JSON format, try http://json2csharp.com/. Once you generate your classes, then you can return your objects like `return Json(yourClassInstance, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to solve your problem

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(int id) 
{ 
  return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});
}
```

Method from the jquery getJSON method by simply...

```
$.getJSON("../SomeActionMethod", { id: someId },
  function(data) {
    alert(data.foo);
    alert(data.baz);
  }
);
```

To serialize json in your controller, may be you can use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm